# Selenium Grid2 and Sikuli

Tags: selenium2, selenium-webdriver, grid, sikuli

Has anyone tried integrating Sikuli to Selenium Grid architecture? I have read many articles online but unfortunately couldn't reach to a solution.

To briefly explain, my scripts are equipped with Sikuli (and Selenium), so after putting Grid into the mix, all my image finds are failing (it will since Sikuli doesn't know about the Node on which tests is running). Just to clarify all my grid nodes are machines having a monitor (not headless).

How to configure Sikuli part of test scripts to verify images on test nodes and not on the hub?

Comment: sikuli is not works with grid because of its working nature,,,i think you know how it works.

Comment: Well firstly how can you say it doesn't work, I hope you had tried integrating them and got some difficulties before putting the comment.

Comment: ya i tried integrating grid with script , i also failed to match just because it takes input as images , differant systems have diff resolution so it cant match images.

Comment: Thanks, the image resolution is just a very minor issue, which can be easily rectified. The major issue is location the node on which test is running and pointing Sikuli to it.